# Google Foobar challenge Power Hungry - failing test no. 3 [hidden] out of 5 test cases?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am doing google foobar challenge power hungry. I am failing in one test case out of 5 test cases which are hidden. Here is my code -

```
def answer(b):
from itertools import combinations
arr = []
for i in range(1,len(b)+1):
    comb = combinations(b,i)
    for j in list(comb):
        mul = 1
        for x in j:
            mul *= x
            if mul > 1000:
                break
            else:
                arr.append(mul)
return str(max(arr))
```

Task is mentioned below -

**Power Hungry**

Commander Lambda's space station is HUGE. And huge space stations take a LOT of power. Huge space stations with doomsday devices take even more power. To help meet the station's power needs, Commander Lambda has installed solar panels on the station's outer surface. But the station sits in the middle of a quasar quantum flux field, which wreaks havoc on the solar panels. You and your team of henchmen has been assigned to repair the solar panels, but you can't take them all down at once without shutting down the space station (and all those pesky life support systems!).

You need to figure out which sets of panels in any given array you can take offline to repair while still maintaining the maximum amount of power output per array, and to do THAT, you'll first need to figure out what the maximum output of each array actually is. Write a function answer(xs) that takes a list of integers representing the power output levels of each panel in an array, and returns the maximum product of some non-empty subset of those numbers. So for example, if an array contained panels with power output levels of [2, -3, 1, 0, -5], then the maximum product would be found by taking the subset: xs[0] = 2, xs[1] = -3, xs[4] = -5, giving the product 2*(-3)*(-5) = 30. So answer([2,-3,1,0,-5]) will be "30".

Each array of solar panels contains at least 1 and no more than 50 panels, and each panel will have a power output level whose absolute value is no greater than 1000 (some panels are malfunctioning so badly that they're draining energy, but you know a trick with the panels' wave stabilizer that lets you combine two negative-output panels to produce the positive output of the multiple of their power values). The final products may be very large, so give the answer as a string representation of the number.

Languages

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py To provide a Java solution, edit solution.java

Test cases

Inputs: (int list) xs = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0] Output: (string) "8"

Inputs: (int list) xs = [-2, -3, 4, -5] Output: (string) "60"

Use verify [file] to test your solution and see how it does. When you are finished editing your code, use submit [file] to submit your answer. If your solution passes the test cases, it will be removed from your home folder.

If possible, please suggest where I am mistaking in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you check if `mul` is greater than 1000?  The constraint  is on individual panels, not the whole array

Comment: Do you know if you are failing test cases because you are running out of time?  Your method seems to be equivalent to generating all subsets of an array, find the product of every subset and return the maximum product.  Since the array can have up to 50 elements this is not practical since there could be up to 2**50 subsets.  [A Better Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subset-array)

Comment: You don't need to store mul (which can become a very large array). You should just update the max so far as each mul is calculated rather than storing them all.

Comment: @SimonCrane I removed the constraint **mul** is greater than 1000 but still getting failed in test case 3.

Comment: It's probably a timing issue then.

Answer (score 5):

So, I worked out the solution and it solved all of my test cases. Bit of an unconventional solution:

- First, check if the array has all zeros, return 0 in that case
- Next, check if there is only one element, and it is negative, return that number
- Next, check if there is only one negative number and the rest are zero, return zero in this case.

#### These are the only exception cases in the program.

---

The next steps are simple:

- Find out the product of all the non-zero numbers.
- If the product is positive, return that number, as it is the largest possible value.
- If the product is negative, divide the number by the least negative number, and return the answer!

  ```
  def solution(xs):

      if(xs.count(0) == len(xs)):
          return(str(0))

      if(len(xs) == 1 and len([n for n in xs if n < 0]) == 1):
          return(str(xs[0]))

      if(len([n for n in xs if n < 0]) == 1 and xs.count(0) == len(xs)-1):
          return(str(0))

      Val = 1

      for i in xs:
          if (i != 0 and i <= 1000):
              Val *= i

      if Val < 0:
          BigNeg = max([n for n in xs if n < 0])
          Val = Val/BigNeg

      return(str(int(Val)))
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Your current algorithm won't scale to handle 50 panels since you would have to generate all 2**50 subsets of subarrays.

> Initial Algorithm

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subset-array/

This method has **O(n)** complexity (as compared to the O(2^n) of the posted method).

```
from random import randint

def maxProductSubset(a, n): 
    if n == 1: 
        return a[0]  

    # Find count of negative numbers, count  
    # of zeros, maximum valued negative  
    # number and product of non-zero numbers  
    max_neg = -999999999999
    count_neg = 0
    count_zero = 0
    prod = 1
    for i in range(n): 

        # If number is 0, we don't  
        # multiply it with product.  
        if a[i] == 0:  
            count_zero += 1
            continue

        # Count negatives and keep  
        # track of maximum valued negative.  
        if a[i] < 0:  
            count_neg += 1
            max_neg = max(max_neg, a[i]) 

        prod = prod * a[i] 

    # If there are all zeros  
    if count_zero == n:  
        return 0

    # If there are odd number of  
    # negative numbers  
    if count_neg & 1:  

        # Exceptional case: There is only  
        # negative and all other are zeros  
        if (count_neg == 1 and count_zero > 0 and 
            count_zero + count_neg == n): 
            return 0

        # Otherwise result is product of  
        # all non-zeros divided by maximum  
        # valued negative.  
        prod = int(prod / max_neg) 

    return str(prod)  # Problem asks for string to be returned

# Test Code
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    big_array = [randint(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(51)]
    tests = [[-1], [-1, 0], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0],  [-2, -3, 4, -5], [ -1, -1, -2, 4, 3 ], big_array ]
    for t in tests:
        print('array {} \n\t max: {}'.format(t, maxProductSubset(t, len(t))))
```

**Output**

```
array [-1] 
     max: -1
array [-1, 0] 
     max: 0
array [2, 0, 2, 2, 0] 
     max: 8
array [-2, -3, 4, -5] 
     max: 60
array [-1, -1, -2, 4, 3] 
     max: 24
array [696, 254, 707, 730, 252, 144, 18, -678, 921, 681, -665, 421, -501, 204, 742, -609, 672, -72, 339, -555, -736, 230, -450, 375, 941, 50, 897, -192, -912, -915, 609, 100, -933, 458, -893, 932, -590, -209, 107, 473, -311, 73, 68, -229, 480, 41, -235, 558, -615, -289, -643] 
     max: 112783193423281396421025291063982496313759557506029207349556366834514274891010648892576460433185005069070271452630069726538629120
```

**Strategy**

Code for algorithm based upon the following [facts](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subset-array/):

1. If there are even number of negative numbers and no zeros, result is
   simply product of all
2. If there are odd number of negative numbers and no zeros, result is
   product of all except the largest valued negative number.
3. If there are zeros, result is product of all except these zeros with
   one exceptional case. The exceptional case is when there is one
   negative number and all other elements are 0. In this case, result
   is 0.

> Alternate Algorithm

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations
from random import randint

def answer(a, n):
    def prod(arr):
        " Multiply elements of array "
        return reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), arr, 1)

    def max_single_sign_prod(arr):
        " Find max product of array assuming all element are same sign "
        if arr[0] == 0:
            return 0  # all zero
        if arr[0] > 0:
            return proc(arr) # all positive

        # all negative
        p = prod(arr)
        if len(arr) > 1 and len(arr) % 2:
            return p // max(arr)
        else:
            return p

    # Generate all positive, all negative and all zero sublists of arr
    pos = [i for i in a if i > 0]
    neg = [i for i in a if i < 0]
    zeros = [i for i in a if i == 0]

    # Find non-empty sublists
    b = [x for x in [pos, neg, zero] if len(x) > 0]

    products = list(map(max_single_sign_prod, b))

    # Find optimal combinations of these product to product max
    # There's only 3**2 or 9 combinations to try
    max_product = max(prod(c) for c in list(comb) for comb in combinations(products, i) for i in range(len(b)+1))

    return str(max_product)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    big_array = [randint(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(51)]
    tests = [[-1], [1], [-1, 0], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0],  [-2, -3, 4, -5], [ -1, -1, -2, 4, 3 ], big_array ]
    for t in tests:
        print('array {} \n\t max: {}'.format(t, maxProductSubset(t, len(t))))
```

**Strategy**

We generate three subsequences from the array:

1. all positive numbers
2. all zeros elements
3. all negative elements

The maximum product for each of these sequences is as follows:

- all positive -- the product of all the numbers
- all zeros -- zero
- all negative -- product of all numbers (for even length) else divide
  the product by the max (if odd length)

We compute the maximum product for each of the non-empty sequences (i.e. all positive, zeros, and negative).

This results in from 1 to 3 products corresponding to the non-empty subsequences.

Our answer is to find the combination of the 1 to 3 products that provides the maximum value.

There are at most 3**2 combinations so this is easily computed.

Comment: Hi by using this method I am able to pass test case 3 but getting failed in test case 4 and 5.

Comment: @ShaikhNaushad--does it provide any information on the type of failure such as "Time Out" or "Wrong Answer"?

Comment: @ShaikhNaushad--are you able to get the data for the test case you're failing?

Comment: @ShaikhNaushad--I updated the code and added an alternate algorithm  Can you give it a try.  This algorithm should be even simpler to follow.

Comment: @DarryIG I have completed the challenge using a code from github which passed all the test cases. By the way thanks for helping me to improve my coding and understanding skills :)

Answer (score 2):

Brute forcing this is intractible. Combinations of 50 items of any size `r` is astronomically huge.

Consider that if you have an even number of negative numbers in your final selection, you'll have a net positive result. Select all of the positive numbers in the list, then select the smallest (absolute value largest) `k` negative numbers in the list where `k % 2 == 0` (i.e. `k` is even) and `k` is as large as possible.

Said differently,

1. Take all the positive numbers. We love positive numbers and they always help us.
2. Take all of the negative numbers.
3. If you have an odd number of negative numbers, omit the one with the largest value (closest to zero).
4. Take the product of the numbers you took after step 3 and return it.

As mentioned by Simon, there's an edge case for a single negative number. All we can do is return it. Similarly, return 0 for situations with no positives, a single negative number and one or more zeroes.

Answer (score -1):

Your code would fail for the test case `b = [-1]`.  The maximum product in this case is 1 (the product of the empty subset).

Comment: Empty subset not allowed since problem states: " ...returns the maximum product of some non-empty subset of those numbers"